# How to change the color of the entire Row in excel , when a drop down is used using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

How to change the background of the entire cell when drop down having two values High and Low using Python and XlsxWriter `data_validation()`?

If High is selected using drop down, entire row has to be green. If Low is selected using drop down, entire row has to be red.

I have used the following lines in my code or i have tried like this

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Reports_Sample.xlsx')   ## Title of the sheet

```
sheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet("Report1")     ## Sheet 1

heading=["A","B","C","D"]

## Now i am adding drop down as High and Low to the column D

sheet1.data_validation('D2:D7', {'validate': 'list',
                                 'source': ['High', 'Low']})
```

If High is clicked, the row should be green. If Low is clicked, the row should be red.

I am unable to add background color for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99% of the stuff that you can do manually with excel you can automate them using xlsxwriter, a powerful library.

With that said this is how i would do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a test df
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4],
                    'B': ['a','b','c','d'],
                    'C': [2.2,np.nan,8.1,9.0],
                    'D': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

# Kickstart the xlsxwriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Define the formats
format_green = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'green'})
format_red = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'red'})

# Apply the data validation rule
worksheet.data_validation('D2:D5', {'validate': 'list',
                            'source': ['High','Low']})

# Apply the conditional formating rules
worksheet.conditional_format('A2:D5', {'type': 'formula',
                            'criteria': '=$D2="High"',
                            'format': format_green})

worksheet.conditional_format('A2:D5', {'type': 'formula',
                            'criteria': '=$D2="Low"',
                            'format': format_red})

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi,this is working fine for me. But it is throwing error when i use openpyxl. Error is "Worksheet" object has no attribute 'add_format'. May i please know what changes need to be done when using openpyxll. I have added                                         
    data_val = DataValidation(type="list",formula1='=$D3:$D9')
    sheet2.add_data_validation(data_val) . It didn't work

Comment: Hello, openpyxl and xlsxwriter might do the same thing (writing excel files) but they are different libraries which use different syntax. Unfortunately i am not familiar with openpyxl, you should either post a question there or read the documentation https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/